# How many dead letter queues should I have on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, dead-letter

Is there a correct number of dead letter queues that I should have? Can my architecture just have one and share across all queues? How should I make this decision?

Thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should probably have one per queue.

There is, presumably, some reason for having multiple Amazon SQS queues, such as having different data or different methods of processing the data.

If a message lands in a Dead Letter Queue, you would need some way of knowing where it came from. I'm not sure if there is any identifying information to discover the original queue. Therefore, it would be best to have one DLQ per normal SQS queue.

Remember -- you should not plan for messages to go into a DLQ. It's there for when things don't go as intended.

Answer (score 0):

The "eventSourceARN": "arn:aws:sqs:us-west-2:460561121586:{event-source-queue-name}" can be used to identify the original queue.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).